# PHP conditional regex

Tags: php, regex, conditional-statements

I dont understand the conditional regex.

*Using preg_match*

I try to get

- always 4 matches
- in middle there is an optional dash
- at the end there is an optional int

**Example**:

```
aaa-bbb-ccc-1
```

"aaa" should be matches[1]

"bbb" should be matches[2]

"ccc" should be matches[3]

"1" should be matches[4]

But there can be an optional dash in bbb. Also the last is optional.

Fe.

```
aaa-bbb-bbb-ccc
```

"aaa" should be matches[1]

"bbb-bbb" should be matches[2]

"ccc" should be matches[3]

"" should be matches[4]

**What i got so far:**

`^(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)-(\d)$`

This works simple with 4 groups.

1-3 expected as letter, number, underscore.

4 expected as digit.

But i dont know how to use the conditions (http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.conditional.php).

Online test: https://regex101.com/r/Ln3f3I/2

Thanks for helping
/cottton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with an optional last group and a non-greedy quantifier in 2nd group:

```
^(\w+)-([\w-]+?)-(\w+)(?:-(\d+))?+$
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ln3f3I/3)

**Regex Details:**

- `^(\w+)-`: Match 1+ word characters at start in 1st group followed by `-`
- `([\w-]+?)-`: Match 1+ word or hyphen characters in 2nd group (lazy) followed by `-`
- `(\w+)`: Match 1+ word characters in 3rd group
- `(?:-(\d+))?+$`: An optional group with hyphen and digits at the end.